# Objective C Sprite Kit Multiple Collisions

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am currently working on a sprite kit game, with Objective-C. So far, I have everything working in order, however I am trying to accomplish multiple collisions and can't seem to accomplish this.

This is my code:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
NSLog(@"contact!");
SKNode * nodeA = contact.bodyA.node;
SKNode *nodeB =contact.bodyB.node;

NSLog(@"%@", nodeA.name);
if ([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"david"] == YES ||
    [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"david"] == NO) {
    [self runAction:self.soundAction];

    SKNode * nodeB = contact.bodyB.node;
    SKAction * remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [nodeB runAction:remove];



    counter++;
    updateLabel = true;
}
else if([contact.bodyA.node.name isEqualToString:@"rock"] == YES ||
        [contact.bodyB.node.name isEqualToString:@"rock"] == YES) {

SKAction * remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
[nodeB runAction:remove];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode * rock = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor orangeColor] size:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
    rock.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + skRand(-40, 40), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 100 + skRand(-40, 40));
    rock.name = @"rock";
    rock.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rock.size];
    rock.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    rock.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0x1;

    [self addChild:rock];

    CGVector dir = CGVectorMake(skRand(-5, 5), skRand(1, 4));
    [rock.physicsBody applyImpulse:dir];
}






}
```

}

Comment: For checking contact you should use categoryBitMasks

Comment: What do you mean by accomplishing multiple collisions?  What contactbitmask and collisionbitmask is assigned to what?